# jQuery form submit encoding issue

Tags: jquery, encoding, utf-8, form-submit

I'm having a problem submitting form with correct encoding.
The thing is when I send form clicking submit button, everything is fine. But when I try to submit it like this

```
$( "#dialogg" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    height: "auto",
    width: "auto",
    show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 300
    },
    hide: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 300
    },
    buttons: {
        "Submit": function() {
            $("#min").val($("#time_spent").val());
            $(this).dialog("close");
            var input = $("<input>")
                .attr("type", "hidden")
               .attr("name", "complete").val("1");
            $("#efr").append($(input));

            $("#efr").submit();
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

I get garbage. There is a html code in a textarea that needs to be sent as an email, that's why very important to get everything encoded correctly.

That is button:

`<button type="button" name="save" class="ui-button-primary" onclick="'."$('#elm1').val($('#efr').find('.nicEdit-main').text()); GetMinutes({$action_id});".'">Send Email</button>`

This didn't help:

`$.ajaxSetup({ scriptCharset: "utf-8" ,contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" });`

Comment: At what point or after which event did you try `.submit()`?

Comment: On button click there is jQuery UI dialog popup with an input. After they input the number it is submitted like this

Comment: You may want to provide more information and a demo if necessary. We don't have a clear picture of what's going on.

Comment: `$("#efr").submit()` by itself is just going to make the browser submit as if you clicked a submit button. There is no ajax involved unless you have set a submit handler....post more code

Comment: GetMinutes just opens the dialog.

Comment: I know it should only submit, but it somewhow the encoding is screwed up. I updated the code.